# Display content for current user and Paid user (Parse)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, parse-platform

*I am using Parse for JavaScript*

I have a user dashboard, that I only want it to be accessed under these two conditions:

1) It is a current user, where they have already login.

2) It is a paid user, where they have already paid their subscription

I have been able to restrict it only to current user by doing the followings:

In the script:

```
angular.module('AuthApp', [])
.run(['$rootScope', function($scope) {
  $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current();
```

In the html

```
<body ng-app="AuthApp">
                  <div ng-show="currentUser">
```

Now for wheter or not they have paid or not, in the database I have added a column known as paid, and where once the user pays a string with the value of "Yes" gets recorded. Hence, **I would also like to restrict to only the current user where the query of Paid is equal to Yes**, but I am not sure how to do that.

In the HTML I know I might have to write

```
  <div ng-show="paidUser">
```

underneath currentUser, but in the script, I am not sure how to pull this off.

Comment: Instead of using a string of Yes or No, why not use a Boolean value such as True or False, with false being your default non paying value? Then on your query to retrieve a valid user, just check to see if the paid column is true and bring back your valid user that way?

Comment: I agree a true or false boolean makes more sense than Yes or No, but my bigger concern is in working it out in the code. I have brainstorrme var query = new Parse.Query("User");
query.equalTo("Paid", "True");    $scope.currentUser = query; but not sure if thats the proper way

Comment: Using $scope.currentUser = Parse.User.current(); would not $scope.currentUser not have the value of $scope.currentUser.paid available? If so, you could easily do a ng-show=currentUser.paid on something. Assuming that you're using a Boolean value.